# Major High Sierra - iOS-14 sync issues

Tags: macos, ios, data-synchronization, upgrade

Everything went well when I upgraded from iOS 12 to iOS 13, except that some iOS-macOS **High Sierra** synchronizations stopped working, or stopped working in full capacity.

Before upgrading to **iOS 14**, I'd like to know. What apps will stop working (as) well between iOS and a macOS MacBook that cannot be upgraded beyond High Sierra. Is the list announced by Apple? Have you seen a list compiled by reporters?

**Update**

As much as I'd love to see examples of good dual-OS apps written by independent developers making it possible to do a bit on macOS, continue from iOS (under the same appleID), then return to macOS, etc, the only good ones I've seen and use are the ones written by Apple.

So to make the question specific. Does upgrading to iOS 14 break any of the following?

1. Notes, e.g.:

- Add a shopping list on macOS. See it on iOS when you're shopping
- Take a photo on iOS. Add the photo to a note. Pick up the picture on macOS.

2. Photos, e.g.:

- Add photos to your list of favorites on macOS. See them on iOS.

3. FaceTime, e.g.:

- Receive a phone call on iOS. Answer with headphones on macOS.

**Related:**

- [Does iOS 14 sync with iTunes 12.8.2.3?](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/itg9fa/does_ios_14_sync_with_itunes_12823/)
- [Manual Photo-Sync from Mac to IOS 14 still broken](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios14/comments/iyc18t/manual_photosync_from_mac_to_ios_14_still_broken/)
- [iOS 14 devices with macOS High Sierra 13.6?](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ios-14-devices-with-macos-high-sierra-13-6.2254587/)
- [Syncing iPhone (iOS 14) with High Sierra using iTunes](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251814814)

Comment: Honest question: how can anyone put such a list together with the thousands of available apps?

Comment: It's a valid question - but, yes, the answer might be tough to find. Perhaps if we limit it to Apple services? This has happened before, when iCloud structures have changed & older machines were left behind.

Comment: @fsb Good point. I took it for granted that we'd be talking about Handoff -type of apps, those written by Apple and built-into the two OSes. Clarified/made more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow High Sierra User:

Apps that live on the web do work well:  E.g. There's an app called grocery gadget where you can keep lists trough their website or on the local device, and sync is nearly instantaneous.  And when I shop with my wife, we both have the app up on our phone, and and as we check off items, they appear checked on the other device. It gets into snit fits and doesn't always sync, but it's only $1.39 per year.

There are several diet/nutrition apps that act similarly with a device app and a website.

Microsoft has phone and ipad versions of their office products.  I'm not a big MS user, so I don't know how functional the phone version.   Google docs is sort of usable on the phone but your working window is tiny.

A lot of Adobe photo products have quite usable ipad versions.  Affinity is another photo app that works on both desktop and ipad.

ForScore is another app that has desktop and ipad versions.  Synchronization has to be pushed, and is not automatic.  Current version requires Catalina on the desktop, but older versions are available.  The feature set prompted me to upgrade one of my machines to catalina.

I have found limitations and glitches when you don't have a good internet connection.  I use an ipad with phone connection in the field.  Updates to my wife's desktop can be delayed.  But cell service in the field runs runs 1-3 bars on Edge.  LTE only happens at the west edge of the field.

Answer (score -1):

I'm running iPadsOS 14.01 on my iPad Pro and Catalina on my iMac. Notes appears to work fine. I haven't tested everything but I did add a picture and it immediately showed up in Notes on my ipad.

I also haven't tested all the options in Photo, but pictures i take on my ipad appear on my iMac as well.

Factime appears to work fine as well.

Again I haven't tested all the options but all 3 seem to work on my iPad Pro and my iMac.

Comment: There was a somewhat big jump between High Sierra and Catalina, so your experience on Catalina may not be too representative.